# Apply post processing shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a Grayscale shader that work when applied to a material.
I'd like to apply it to what the camera renders.

I found some tutorial speaking about
void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)

but I wasn't able to make it work with mine.

The shader :

```
Shader "Custom/Grayscale" {

SubShader {
    Pass{

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma exclude_renderers gles
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        uniform sampler2D _MainTex;

        fixed4 frag(v2f_img i) : COLOR{
            fixed4 currentPixel = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

            fixed grayscale = Luminance(currentPixel.rgb);
            fixed4 output = currentPixel;

            output.rgb = grayscale;
            output.a = currentPixel.a;

            //output.rgb = 0;

            return output;
        }

        ENDCG
    }

}

FallBack "VertexLit"
}
```

And the script attached to the camera :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Grayscale : ImageEffectBase {

void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination) {
    Graphics.Blit (source, destination, material);
}
}
```

Any suggestions ?
Many thanks !

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a vertex shader because there's no default vertex shader. This one just copies data from vertex buffer.

```
#pragma vertex vert
v2f_img vert (appdata_base v) {
    v2f_img o;
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
    o.uv = v.texcoord;
    return o;
}
```

**AND ALSO** you jave to add `ZTest Always` after `Pass {`.

This is clearly a bug but Unity3d support says that they left it this way (that default ZTest is used) not to alter shaders behavior. I hope they'll reconsider this and make that `ZTest Always` is used by default for `Graphics.Blit`.